# ::Deep with SASS + VS 2022 + Blazor = Only Allowed in filenames ending with .razor.css or cshtml.cs Warning

Tags: css, visual-studio, sass, blazor

I am using sass with my blazor application and using "DartSassBuilder" so I have something like this

```
Add.razor
  Add.razor.scss
    Add.razor.css
```

Now in my "scss" file I have

```
::deep .search-btn {
   margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Which gives me this warning

> :deep is only allowed in file names ending with ".razor.css" or
> .cshtml.css"

I see it in the .css file it gets rendered to

```
::deep .search-btn {margin-left: 10px;}
```

So it should work fine but wondering how I can get rid of the warning.

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue in VS. I updated from 17.9.0 to 17.9.2 and it is fixed.